# How do I delay text from being displayed in textView - using input from the user

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple application where every so many seconds the text being displayed is changed to another, the input is given by the user before the onClick and set to different strings.  I can't find a way to have the different strings displayed at different times - and is it even possible to use one single textView to display different text at different times, never at the same time....

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Andrew

This is my code so far...

```
public class ThunderActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //when the game button is pressed
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Enter names
            //player one
            final EditText player1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final String player = player1.getText().toString().trim();
            //player 2
            final EditText player2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            final String player11 = player2.getText().toString().trim();
            //player 3
            final EditText player3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            final String player111 = player3.getText().toString().trim();

            //switches to second screen - the play xml file
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);

            //starts the song
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.thunderstruck);
            mp.start();

            //shuffle names and display them

            //displays name - testing purposes
            v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String text = player;
            ((TextView) v).setText(text);
            //v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            //String text2 = player11;
            //((TextView) v).setText(text2);    
        }           
    });           
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do the same thing is using the `Handler.postDelayed` method.

```
public class Act extends Activity{

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private TextView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Initialize view

        handler.postDelayed(new ViewUpdater("str1", view), 10000);
        handler.postDelayed(new ViewUpdater("str2", view), 20000);
        handler.postDelayed(new ViewUpdater("str2", view), 30000);
    }

    private class ViewUpdater implements Runnable{
        private String mString;
        private TextView mView;

        public ViewUpdater(String string, TextView view){
            mString = string;
            mView = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mView.setText(mString);
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that: You get the basic idea!

Comment: I really like what you gave me but I was wondering if you could go a little more in detail on how I can use this in my scenario.  I'm learning as I go, so I appreciate any more help you can give me!

Comment: Think of it like you are issuing a command which will be executed at the specified time. Plan out how you want to issue your commands, and for each command, pass on a new Runnable (the command) to the handler (the command executor). Please let me know if you need help with the actual code, in which case, please specify your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

ok here is your hint:

Say your `TextView` is called `yourTextView`

```
String[] texts = new String[]{"String1","String2","String3"}; //etc
Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
            synchronized(this){
                wait(30000); //wait 30 seconds before changing text
            }
            //to change the textView you must run code on UI Thread so:
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    yourTextView.setText(texts[i]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
Thread T = new Thread(myRun);
T.start();
```

Comment: I get the error - The local variable myRun may not have been initialized - with the "myRun"

Comment: i edited the answer ... I added `Threat T` at the end and changed `synchronized(this)`

Comment: Everything seems to look good...Although the only problem is at the bottom, it gives me this error - Cannot instantiate the type Runnable

Thanks for the help by the way, I'm a super noob at this

Comment: I edited the answer and I answered you on the other question. Please Tick beside this answer and that (:

Answer (score 0):

A more correct answer would be to use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). You can add all your `TextViews` to it and call `startFlipping()`. You can set the flip interval by calling `setFlipInterval(int milliseconds)`.